# Cannot get the simplest ajax call to work

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying the following code in my browser's console.

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://stackoverflow.com/', 
    dataType: 'html', 
    success: function() { 
        console.log("Yes, this works."); 
    } 
});
```

**Why don't I receive my message in the console?**

I do receive the following code.

```
Object { readyState=1, getResponseHeader=function(), getAllResponseHeaders=function(), more...}
```

Comment: cross browser requests are forbidden by browsers

Comment: Have to keep ajax requests in same domain

Comment: And if I control both domains, isn't there any work around?

Comment: ajax is there to partially update your own website. why stackoverflow.com?

Comment: Works for me, you just have to run the code in console while you're on SO

Comment: @FellowStranger route the request through your server to your client

Comment: Fellow you must send **JSONP** from one of your domains and use getJSON to receive the data from the other

Comment: do you control stackoverflow.com ?

Comment: the property `crossDomain:true` will also be a valid solution to do a cross domain request

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you control both domains and have access to server configuration, you can enable Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) to allow AJAX requests from one domain to access the other. The steps for enabling CORS depends on your specific web server (e.g. Apache, node, nginx, IIS, etc.) Dr. Google should be able to give you the specifics.

And to answer your specific question, you don't see a console message because the AJAX request never succeeds.